# Подключиться к outlook с помощью python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, outlook

Использую outlook, есть потребность читать скриптом входящую почту. Но письма хранятся не на сервере Exchange, а на локали. В связи с чем вопрос, как можно периодически опрашивать файл mail.pst? и можно ли? win32com сможет?

Comment: примеры кода с  imaplib: [Получить список папок почтового ящика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/820767/23044) и [How do I print multiple email bodies with python imap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22159037/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Делал [подобную задачу](https://github.com/gil9red/ordering_lunch_at_Nashe_Vse) через [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imaplib.html) и [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html#module-email). Только мне нужно было от сервера почты запросить все id писем за неделю от указанного отправителя, взять последнее и вытащить из него `docx` вложенный файл.

Вам нужно узнать адрес почтового сервера (я вроде бы в настройках аутлука смотрел) и использовать логин / пароль.

Из того кода я сделал небольшой пример:

```
import email
import imaplib

from datetime import date, timedelta

connect = imaplib.IMAP4(config.smtp_server)
connect.login(config.username, config.password)
connect.select()

# Если не ограничивать датой, соберет все письма и запрос будет дольше выполняться
today = date.today()
week_ago = today - timedelta(weeks=1)
since = week_ago.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')

typ, msgnums = connect.search(None, 'HEADER From', config.lunch_email, 'SINCE', since)
id_list = msgnums[0].split()
if not id_list:
    raise Exception('Письма не найдены.')

last_id = id_list[-1]
last_id_int = int(last_id.decode())

# Запрос письма
typ, data = connect.fetch(last_id, '(RFC822)')
msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])

# Получаем заголовок письма
data, charset = email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]
subject = data.decode(charset).strip().replace('\t', ' ')
print('Subject: "{}".'.format(subject))
```

Comment: Спасибо, а c ntlm-авторизацией виндовой проблем не будет? Ща попробую)