# Получить список папок почтового ящика

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите, как получить список папок почтового ящика (чтобы и русские имена корректно отображались)? Использую python 3.6, модуль imapclient

Comment: Попробуйте привести в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методами стандартной библиотеки, список папок (mailbox) с imap сервера можно получить, с помощью [`.list()` метода](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.list):

```
import imaplib
import shlex
import ssl

imap_host = "imap.yandex.ru"
with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host, ssl_context=ssl.create_default_context()) as mail:
    mail.login('login', 'password')
    for folder in mail.list()[1]:
        print(shlex.split(imaputf7decode(folder.decode()))[-1])
```

Чтобы не-ascii имена поддерживать, используется [модифицированная utf-7 кодировка (rfc 3501)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.1.3), реализованная здесь в [функции `imaputf7decode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787169/4279).

Пример вывода:

```
Отправленные
Исходящие
Спам
Удаленные
Черновики
Archives
INBOX
Junk
```