# Imap выбрать папку на русском языке

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите, как выбрать папку имя которой на русском языке?

Пробовал такими вариантами:

```
mail.select('&BB0ENQQ2BDUEOwQwBEIENQQ7BEwEPQQwBE8 &BD8EPgRHBEIEMA-')
mail.select('Какое-то имя')
mail.select(b'&BB0ENQQ2BDUEOwQwBEIENQQ7BEwEPQQwBE8 &BD8EPgRHBEIEMA-')
mail.select(b'(\\Unmarked \\HasNoChildren) "|" "&BB0ENQQ2BDUEOwQwBEIENQQ7BEwEPQQwBE8- &BD8EPgRHBEIEMA-"')
```

Но результат один - ошибка

> imaplib.error: SELECT command error: BAD [b'Command syntax error.
>   sc=opAqN91F5uQ1_290051_43j']

python 3.6, imaplib

Answer (score 0):

Строка в вопросе, не интерпретируется как `imap4-utf-7`:

```
>>> import twisted.mail.imap4
>>> b'&BB0ENQQ2BDUEOwQwBEIENQQ7BEwEPQQwBE8 &BD8EPgRHBEIEMA-'.decode('imap4-utf-7')
'Нежелательная &BD8EPgRHBEIEMA-'
```

Для значений, возвращаемых из [`.list()` метода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820831/23044) работает:

```
folder = '"&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-"'  # Sent
folder = '"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"'
```

```
>>> b'"&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-"'.decode('imap4-utf-7')
'"Отправленные"'
>>> b'"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"'.decode('imap4-utf-7')
'"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"'
```

Полный пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ssl
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL

folder = '"&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-"'
imap_host = "imap.yandex.ru"
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
with IMAP4_SSL(imap_host, ssl_context=ssl_context) as mail_client:
    mail_client.login('login', 'password')
    ok, [num] = mail_client.select(folder, readonly=True)
    print(int(num))
```